# How to submit traditional blade form from livewire component?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am trying to reuse laravel's default authentication components in livewire component. But when the login form is submitting I am getting a console error

> wire-directives.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> null (reading 'match')

The login form working perfectly fine when I am using the default login blade. But when I am reusing the login form in my livewire component, it is not working. Here is my code:
In my livewire component, I have this

```
<div>                
  <x-login-form/>
</div>
```

and the login form component is laravels default login form:

```
<form role="form" class="text-start" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group input-group-outline my-3">
      <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" :value="old('email')" required placeholder="email">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-outline mb-3">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-switch d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"  id="remember_me"  name="remember">
      <label class="form-check-label mb-0 ms-2" for="rememberMe">Remember Me</label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn bg-gradient-primary w-100 my-4 mb-2">Sign In</button>
    </div>
    @if (Route::has('password.request'))
    <p class="text-xs text-center">
      <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}" class="text-info text-gradient font-weight-bold">Forgot your password?</a>
    </p>
    @endif
  </form>
```

Comment: And you get that error if you comment out that component from your Livewire view?

Comment: No. I am just getting this error while trying to submit the form from the livewire component.